# Executing SCP in GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, scp, gnu-parallel

I need to run some commands in parallel including SCP. For this I'm using GNU Parallel. The problem is I don't know how to pass the password to SCP. This is a line similar to the one I'm running:

```
ls 2011_* | parallel scp {} user@domain
```

And if `ls` finds 3 files, scp ask 3 times for password at the same time and I can only input the password to the last process to prompt for it.

I temporarily solved this issue connecting using a public key, but this won't be an option in the future due to company policies. I read the SCP man pages and I couldn't find an option, but I'm quite confident that Parallel should have an option to allow me to input the password.

Somebody knows a way to solve this?

**EDIT:** I want to know if there is a way I can tell `parallel` the password so it can give it to `scp` each time it asks for it. Maybe with something like this:

```
ls 2011_* | parallel scp {} user@domain < file_with_password.txt
```

But specifying that the redirection of `STDIN` is for `scp` and not for `ls` or `parallel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to look at `ssh-agent`: The benefit of having a passphrase protected certificate with the convenience of typing your passphrase only once.

GNU Parallel >= 20220322 supports this syntax if you have `sshpass` installed:

```
parallel -S user:password@server ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parallel sshpass -p $PASS scp -P $PORT -rp {} ~/to_dir ::: $ADDRESS:~/from_dir/*
```

Comment: EDIT:

parallel sshpass -p $PASS scp -P $PORT -rp {} ~/to_dir ::: $ADDRESS:~/from_dir/*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Also, you can [edit] your answer, no need to add comments to indicate it. I've edited it for you to add your change and fix code formatting (four spaces for code highlighting).